# Track progress of ZipArchive unzipping

Tags: c#

I was pleasantly surprised to discover in .net 4.5 I can connect an HTTP client stream to a Zip archive and get it unzipped on the local file system.
Here is the code that does it:

```
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string url = "http://www.example.com/abc.zip";
        Stream zipReadingStream = wc.OpenRead(url);
        System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zip = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(zipReadingStream);
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(zip, "C:\\ExtractHere");
```

It works fine. But I want to keep track of the progress. I tried to check the Position property of the stream but I got Not Supported error message. Is there other way to do it?

Comment: I had the same problem, and i got an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661211/extract-an-archive-with-progress-bar