# Extract an archive with progress bar?

Tags: c#, windows

How i can use an progress bar in this case?

```
void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Update Complete!", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filePathDir + "/" + filename, filePathDir);
}
```

EDIT:
@Alessandro D'Andria , But in this case?:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
Stream zipReadingStream = wc.OpenRead(url);
ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipReadingStream);
ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(zip, filePathDir);
```

Comment: By handling the `DownloadProgressChanged` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne: He's asking about extract a ZIP file, not `WebClient`.

Comment: You cannot, the best you can do, with the default implementation in `System.IO.Compression`, are extracting every file manually and keep track of the progress.

Comment: @Alessandro D'Andria and how i can track the progress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the source of [`ExtractToDirectory` on GitHub](http://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/System/IO/Compression/ZipFileExtensions.cs,088b102afeb57ad6), the only thing you need to do is pass in a [`Progress<ZipProgress>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) and call it inside the foreach loop.

```
//This is a new class that represents a progress object.
public class ZipProgress
{
    public ZipProgress(int total, int processed, string currentItem)
    {
        Total = total;
        Processed = processed;
        CurrentItem = currentItem;
    }
    public int Total { get; }
    public int Processed { get; }
    public string CurrentItem { get; }
}

public static class MyZipFileExtensions
{
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName, IProgress<ZipProgress> progress)
    {
        ExtractToDirectory(source, destinationDirectoryName, progress, overwrite: false);
    }

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName, IProgress<ZipProgress> progress, bool overwrite)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        if (destinationDirectoryName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationDirectoryName));


        // Rely on Directory.CreateDirectory for validation of destinationDirectoryName.

        // Note that this will give us a good DirectoryInfo even if destinationDirectoryName exists:
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
        string destinationDirectoryFullPath = di.FullName;

        int count = 0;
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in source.Entries)
        {
            count++;
            string fileDestinationPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryFullPath, entry.FullName));

            if (!fileDestinationPath.StartsWith(destinationDirectoryFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                throw new IOException("File is extracting to outside of the folder specified.");

            var zipProgress = new ZipProgress(source.Entries.Count, count, entry.FullName);
            progress.Report(zipProgress);

            if (Path.GetFileName(fileDestinationPath).Length == 0)
            {
                // If it is a directory:

                if (entry.Length != 0)
                    throw new IOException("Directory entry with data.");

                Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDestinationPath);
            }
            else
            {
                // If it is a file:
                // Create containing directory:
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestinationPath));
                entry.ExtractToFile(fileDestinationPath, overwrite: overwrite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is used like

```
public class YourClass
{
    public Progress<ZipProgress> _progress;

    public YourClass()
    {
        // Create the progress object in the constructor, it will call it's ReportProgress using the sync context it was constructed on.
        // If your program is a UI program that means you want to new it up on the UI thread.
        _progress = new Progress<ZipProgress>();
        _progress.ProgressChanged += Report
    }

    private void Report(object sender, ZipProgress zipProgress)
    {
        //Use zipProgress here to update the UI on the progress.
    }

    //I assume you have a `Task.Run(() => Download(url, filePathDir);` calling this so it is on a background thread.
    public void Download(string url, string filePathDir)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Stream zipReadingStream = wc.OpenRead(url);
        ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipReadingStream);
        zip.ExtractToDirectory(filePathDir, _progress);
    }

    //...
```

Comment: @cott Chamberlain I have that error:
"_progress" does exist, this should be a string?

Comment: @ProGamersRo i did not include the field decliration in the code example because I thought it was obvious that it needed to be done. I updated the example with it.

Comment: @cott Chamberlain ,Now i have an error at: ReportProgress
Error:
http://i.imgur.com/MiEW6l9.png

Comment: It was a typo, I wrote this thing in the web browser. It should have been `ProgressChanged` not `ReportProgress` When stuff like that happens you should try and check the documentation.

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain and the last error, sorry i forgot to put that error in the last comment:
No overload for method "ExtractToDirectory" takes 3 arguments.

Comment: @ProGamersRo another typo caused by me copying and pasting your code. it should be `zip.ExtractToDirectory(filePathDir, _progress);` or `MyZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(zip, filePathDir, _progress);`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xzH7yI3.png
This is the report

Like this should look like?
At void report i have this:
            updatePercentText.Content = zipProgress;

Comment: Its not a string, you actually need to use the properties on the class and use the properites of the `ZipProgress` object to build up the string that will be displayed on screen. If you are going to do a % be careful of integer division, make sure you cast one of the properties to a `double` before you divide: `updatePercentText.Content = ((double)zipProgress.Processed) / zipProgress.Total * 100);`

Comment: Thanks a lot!, But when i press the button to download those files the application is freeze and the is 100%, is that going to be a problem?

Comment: I see you overlooked the comment I put in `//I assume you have a 'Task.Run(() => Download(url, filePathDir);' calling this so it is on a background thread.` You can't call `ExtractToDirectory` on the UI thread it is too slow. You need to call it on a background thread.

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain Can you give me an example in code?, i mean where i need to put that? P.S. Is the first time when i am working with Task.Run

Comment: No, you need to go find a basic tutorial on how to do background work with WPF and read it.

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain Ok, I did that, but the UI is updateing just at at the final:
http://i.imgur.com/zn1EbU4.png

Comment: Then that means there is likely one one file in the zip. So going from 0 out of 1 files complete (0%) to 1 out of 1 files complete (100%) if you want progress within the file you will need to make your own `ExtractToFile` method that reports progress as the data is copied. And before you ask that is too much work to do in this SO question. Go try and do it yourself using what you learned and when you get stuck ask a new question.

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain How i can acces: zipProgress.Processed and zipProgress.Total in another code, because i got this error when i try to access them: Use of unsigned local variable "zipProgress".

Comment: Once again, you need to take a step back and start doing basic tutorials in C#. If you want to become a programmer you must be willing to do research and learn on your own. If you just wait to be spoon fed answers and you use code you find online without understanding what is happening in the code you will never progress beyond the most simple programs.

Comment: @madocter you can't extend a static class. The class does not inherit `ZipFileExtensions` it adds a extension method on to ZipArchive, I just happen to call it `MyZipFileExtension` the name could have been anything.

Comment: I love this although I think creating a new ZipProgress() for each file is too much heap allocation, you can just add your own event to the ZipProgress class create only one, pass it in directly instead of IProgress<ZipProgress> and call its event instead

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from making ZipProgress a struct instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can work for you:

```
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipReadingStream))
{
    var totalProgress = archive.Entries.Count;

    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        entry.ExtractToFile(destinationFileName); // specify the output path of thi entry

        // update progess there
    }
}
```

It's simple a workaround to keep track of the progress.

Comment: take a look to EDIT, Please